# Saving data in for loops/ using apply instead

Tags: r, for-loop

What are the common ways of saving data within for loops?? If x is a list, I normally use something like this:

```
 x <- data.frame("a"=1:10,"b"=11:20,"c"=11:20,"d"=21:30)

 for(i in 1:length(x[[1]])){
                     y <- (x[[i,2]]-x[[i,4]])/(x[[i,2]]+x[[i,4]])
                     x$newcolumn <- c(x$newcolumn,y)
 }
```

The thing is it didn`t always make a new column in the x with the number of length(x[[1]]). Sometimes it is double so long and/or only saves the last calculation for all of them, or only makes 0s. I also tried "apply" functions to make it quicker but I´m not able to make a function like in "y" without the indexing ("i") that works.

An additional question beyond of these one: would it be possible to order/sort the dataframe lets say by (x$newcolumn) with a function that doesn`t order by alphabet rather by your own criteria?

Comment: Are you trying to just do `x$newcolumn <- (x$b-x$d)/(x$b+x$d)`? If not, please edit the question to make the goal of your code more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it's important to distinguish lists and dataframes; while all dataframes are lists, the inverse is not true. Lists can contain vectors of differents lengths, for instance. So looping can give unexpected results with "heteroenous" lists.

Now about the looping in your example, well, you don't need any.

```
x$newcolumn <- (x$b - x$d) / (x$b + x$d)
```

is sufficient. You could also write

```
x$newcolumn <- (x[,2] - x[,4]) / (x[,2] + x[,4])
```

The fact that you have inconsistent results should make you stop and try to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. But if you really *insist* on using a loop, you could do it like this:

```
x$newcolumn <- NA
for(i in seq_len(nrow(x))) {
  x$newcolumn[i] <- (x[i,2] - x[i,4]) / (x[i,2] + x[i,4])
}
```

with *single* brackets. You'd really need to do this only in some special circumstances, and there's almost always a way to avoid loops, even though sometimes it's only by "hiding" the looping process, such as in:

```
x$newcolumn <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) { 
                       (x[i,2] - x[i,4]) / (x[i,2] + x[i,4]))
                      })
```

Here, the iterator is i just like in the loop above. Grossly put, you just trade the "for" for an "lapply" function.

For ordering in a custom manner, I suggest you search SO in more depth, you'll find that question has been asked plenty of times already...